# Mockito: How to mock a method with Mono<> in param and return types

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit-jupiter

I am working with Junit5 Jupiter and mockito. I have added the mockito extension on top of my test class: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.

This piece of code does not work in a test keeps failing:

```
MyService myService = mock(MyService.class);
when(myService.get(Mono.just("TEXT"))).thenReturn(Mono.just(new BusinessObject("blabla")));
```

The error is

```
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'get' method:
    myService.get(
    MonoJust
);
    -> at com.myapp.service.CustomerService.getCustomersIds(CustomerService.java:59)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. myService.get(
    MonoJust
);
```

How can I mock a method that takes a `Mono<String>` as input and that returns another `Mono<BusinessObject>` in output?

Comment: Will this do: Replace `Mono.just("TEXT")` with `Mockito.any(Object.class)`. From`https://stackoverflow.com/a/66328327/14072498

Comment: I don't want any object in input, I want a specific String because I will mock another TEXT in my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution by using `thenAnswer()`.

```
when(myService.get(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    Mono<String> monoInputParam = invocation.getArgument(0);
    // Here, build the output business object according to what you get in input param
    BusinessObject businessObject = businessObjectsMap.get(monoInputParam.block())
    return Mono.just(businessObject);
});
```

This way, my mock is "dynamic" because I can return something different according to the input param.

`businessObjectsMap` is a Map<String, BusinessObject> prepared in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm not a reactor user, treat this answer as speculation.

`Mono` is a class.
Create either a mock of it that you return or an instance that you return.
Something is calling the service and passing the Mono parameter.
Stub that thing and have it call your service with the mock or instance that you created.
Then compare to that mock or instance.
Also, learn how to use annotations.
Here is some possible code:

```
@Mock
private MyService mockMyService;

private BusinessObject liveBusinessObject;

private Mono<String> liveMono;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach()
{
  liveBusinessObject = new BusinessObject("blabla");
  liveMono = Mono.just("blam");
}

@Test
void testBlammy()
{
  doReturn(liveBusinessObject).when(mockMyService).get(liveMono);

  // other wiring required, but is not clear from the example code.
  // specifically, whatever calls the MyService.get must call with
  // the liveMono instance as the parameter.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was basically what I tried (but without preparing my objects in the @BeforeEach). I have just found a solution that works, will add a new answer. I am sure it can be useful for other people!